# Solana Script in Python

Tags: python, cli

I am writing a python program using solana CLI commands as strings:

TransW1_W2 = 'solana transfer --from ~/[WALLET1]/my-keypair.json [WALLET2 ADDRESS] 1 --with the rest of the command... Notice, after the [WALLET2 ADDRESS] is '1' that is the amount.This has worked fine. I use the os.system(TransW1_W2) command.

However, I want to allow user input of the amount via amount1 = float(input("Size of Amount:  "))

When I substitute amount1 for the 1 in the command, I get this error: error: Invalid value for '': Unable to parse input amount as integer or float, provided: amount1

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you print the value of input before you call float? that will tell you if you are reading the input correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I verified the amount value with a print statement before the transfer request, and it is the float value.